# Replacement MTB rear derailleur

Tags: mountain-bike

I need to replace a Shimano Deore RD-M531 rear derailleur which has a long cage (9 speed cassette). I can replace the derailleur no problem, but my knowledge isn't great and am just not sure what to replace it with. This is an old bike and I would be happy with second hand to minimise costs. I would buy the same but none available on line. Any suggestions?
Thanks
Matt

Comment: That should read Shimano Deore RD-M531

Comment: Probably best to ask at your LBS (Local Bike Shop) rather than just ordering something over the internet...

Answer (score 1):

Shimano Deore RD-M591 is a comparable part which you can still find -- this is probably what I'd use. If you want to go a bit cheaper, Shimano Acera M360 will work too.

You can use any 7-9 speed Shimano rear derailleur to replace another 7-9 speed Shimano rear derailleur provided it has the appropriate capacity (*) for your setup (at least big chainring - small chainring + big cassette cog - small cassette cog) and largest cog rating, since the cable pull is the same. 10 speed onwards has a few more cases.

(*) Capacities tend to be conservative -- you can usually exceed them by a bit if you don't use absurd gear combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend staying far away from used derailleurs, generally by the time they are taken off a bike, they do not function as they should. (bent hanger or cage, etc...)

Check ebay for good deals,
[When I searched this you could buy one for $23.50 shipped](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Derailleurs-Rear-/177813/i.html?_from=R40&LH_ItemCondition=3&_dcat=177813&Number%2520of%2520Speeds=9%2520speed&_sop=15&_nkw=Shimano%20RD&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1&_trksid=p2045573.m1684)

Comment: I take your point. Looking at the used ones on ebay doesn't fill me with much hope. Thanks